# Matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap en Python

Tags: python

Estoy entrando en el mundo de machine-learning en Python por medio de un libro. Viendo el modelo del perceptrón, donde "X" son los valores de entrada e "y" los valores de salida, hay dos líneas del código que no entiendo lo que significan:

````
cmap = ListedColormap(colors[:len(np.unique(y))])``` y ```plt.scatter (x=X[y == cl, 0], y= X[y == cl, 1], alpha=0.8, c=colors[idx], marker= markers [idx], label = cl, edgecolor = 'black')
````

```
def plot_decision_regions(X, y, classifier, resolution=0.02):
    # setup marker generator and color map
    markers = ('s', 'x', 'o', '^', 'v')
    colors = ('red', 'blue', 'lightgreen', 'gray', 'cyan')
    cmap = ListedColormap(colors[:len(np.unique(y))])
    # plot the decision surface
    x1_min, x1_max = X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1
    x2_min, x2_max = X[:, 1].min() - 1, X[:, 1].max() + 1
    xx1, xx2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x1_min, x1_max, resolution),
        np.arange(x2_min, x2_max, resolution))
    Z = classifier.predict(np.array([xx1.ravel(), xx2.ravel()]).T)
    Z = Z.reshape(xx1.shape)
    plt.contourf(xx1, xx2, Z, alpha=0.4, cmap=cmap)
    plt.xlim(xx1.min(), xx1.max())
    plt.ylim(xx2.min(), xx2.max())
    # plot class samples
    for idx, cl in enumerate(np.unique(y)):
    plt.scatter(x=X[y == cl, 0], y=X[y == cl, 1],alpha=0.8, 
    c=cmap(idx),marker=markers[idx], label=cl, edgecolor= black)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si la pregunta es ¿que hacen esas líneas?, la primera genera un objeto "paleta de colores" a partir de una lista nombres de colores validos en matplotlib.colors o a partir de números que representen colores(rgb o rgba), unique en este caso "sobra", pero supongo que está para garantizar que no se repita ningún color en la paleta.

la segunda genera un objeto grafico de puntos (scatter) y como lo veo le pone un solo punto a la vez, que cumpla con el criterio de ser igual a c1, el cual se va actualizando con los valores únicos de la variable "y" y le va poniendo el color definido en el colormap (de la línea con ListedColormap). Las otras banderas como markers es para poner marcadores como se define en la variable "markers" (representan puntos, cruces...) y labels es para que quede con el nombre

Comment: Gracias, me fue de utilidad